# Wait for 1 promise before all other promises

Tags: javascript, promise

Apologize in advance about the ambiguous title.

To better explain the question - I have two functions in a `fetch-form-data.js` that look something like...

```
let cachedBaseUrl;

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (cachedBaseUrl) return Promise.resolve(cachedBaseUrl)

  return fetch('https://some-baseurl-endpoint.com')
    .then(baseUrl => {
      cachedBaseUrl = baseUrl
      return baseUrl
    });
}

const getFormData = formId =>
  getBaseUrl()
    .then(baseUrl => fetch('https://form-data-endpoint.com'))

module.exports = {
  getFormData
}
```

`getFormData` is exported and called hundreds of times in a loop elsewhere. The problem is `getFormData` depends on `getBaseUrl`, so calling `getFormData` hundreds of times also calls `getBaseUrl` hundreds of times, which frequently errors because I'm guessing the baseUrl endpoint doesn't like getting hit so rapidly.

I would like to instead ensure that `getBaseUrl` only gets hit once, and have all subsequent `getFormData` calls "wait" on `getBaseUrl` resolving before moving on.

One solution would be to export both `getBaseUrl` and `getFormData` wherever `getFormData` is being used, await `getBaseUrl`, then call `getFormData` however many times as needed. Something like...

```
async () => {
  const baseUrl = await getBaseUrl();
  const formData = [];

  for (let form of forms) {
    formData.push(getFormData(form));
  }

  await Promise.all(formData);
  ...
}
```

However, the usage of `getFormData` is spread across the codebase. It would be nice to simply abstract away `getBaseUrl` as is the current implementation and only expose `getFormData`, but solve the issue of "awaiting" all subsequent `getFormData` calls until at least the first `getBaseUrl` call is resolved.

My feeble attempt is to cache baseUrl, as seen in the above codeblock, but that doesn't "stop" immediate subsequent `getBaseUrl` calls from occurring, which calls another `fetch` because nothing is cached yet.

How would I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: Cache the Base Url in `GetBaseUrl()`?  Oh, wait.

Comment: So your problem is that your cache isn't working, right?

Comment: My feeble attempt is to cache baseUrl, as seen in the above codeblock, but that doesn't "stop" immediate subsequent getBaseUrl calls from occurring, which calls another fetch because nothing is cached yet.

Comment: Instead of saying `if (cachedBaseUrl)`, which is clearly always returns false, try comparing `cachedBaseUrl` against some value that will reliably indicate whether your cache has been filled or not.

Comment: `cachedBaseUrl` eventually becomes true after the endpoint returns baseUrl, which tends to take 1-2 seconds. Prior to that 1-2 seconds, `getBaseUrl` is already called hundreds of times, which of course triggers `fetch` hundreds of times because `cachedBaseUrl` is still false until the first response is returned

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem.

Comment: Cache the Promise not the value to which it resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your caching solution is a good start, by caching the pending promise as well I think it solves the problem elegantly.

```
let cachedBaseUrl;

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (cachedBaseUrl) return Promise.resolve(cachedBaseUrl)
  return cachedBaseUrl = fetch('https://some-baseurl-endpoint.com');
}

const getFormData = formId =>
  getBaseUrl()
    .then(baseUrl => fetch('https://form-data-endpoint.com'))

module.exports = {
  getFormData
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
let cachedBaseUrl;
const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (cachedBaseUrl) return cachedBaseUrl
  return cachedBaseUrl = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      fetch('https://some-baseurl-endpoint.com')
          .then(BaseUrl => { cachedBaseUrl = undefined; resolve(BaseUrl) })
          .catch(() => { cachedBaseUrl = undefined; reject() })
  );
}
```

You need to stop `getBaseUrl()` from sending other requests before the first request completes. So you need a Promise of **that** request, not a `Promise.resolve(constant)`.

After request completes you set its result with `resolve/reject` and reset `cachedBaseUrl`, so you can pass the `if` and try again.

Reset logic is up to you. You can deside to fetch baseurl-endpoint constantly but sequentially (as it is done right now), or from time to time, then you will have to call `SetTimeout(interval, () => cachedBaseUrl = undefined)` instead of just `cachedBaseUrl = undefined`. Or do what ever you like.

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: @Robert Harvey made an edit, hope this clarifies my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just cache your promise also.

```
let cachedBaseUrl, cachedPromise;

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (cachedBaseUrl) return Promise.resolve(cachedBaseUrl)
  if (cachedPromise) return cachedPromise;

  cachedPromise = fetch('https://some-baseurl-endpoint.com')
    .then(baseUrl => {
      cachedBaseUrl = baseUrl
      return baseUrl
    });

  return cachedPromise;
}

const getFormData = formId =>
  getBaseUrl()
    .then(baseUrl => fetch('https://form-data-endpoint.com'))

module.exports = {
  getFormData
}
```

Comment: doesn't solve his problem of needing to not overwhelm the getBaseUrl API endpoint ( according to one of his OP comments)

Comment: @Oliver I have tested and doesn't overwhelm the getBaseUrl API endpoint just call 1 time.

Comment: he's calling getFormData (which needs the getBaseUrl) several hundred times in rapid succession. in this case, he needs to have status'ing or or something else setup to prevent hundreds of API calls from overloading the endpoint. your code works fine otherwise though AFAIK

Comment: @Oliver, you're mistaken. In subsequent calls to `getBaseUrl` in this solution, the `if (cachePromise) return ...` condition prevents additional requests from being sent.

Comment: @guest caching (in any of the current posted implementations) does not solve the precise problem he is talking about. all of them solve one problem adequately (which is upon successfully getting the base url, having getBaseUrl just return the URL). the problem is that this still overwhelms the getBaseURL endpoint since that initial call and promise does not resolve immediately - more calls are made in the interim (in this case, several hundred).  he needs to handle this manually so that he only fires one API call to getBaseURL() and his program will refuse to send more

Comment: @Oliver just tested and lets see.

Comment: @Oliver I think you might be missing that `fetch(...).then(...)` evaluates to a Promise object synchronously, which populates `cachedPromise` synchronously. A Promise object is truthy even when it is unresolved, so the proposed `getBaseUrl` here would return that cached Promise without making more requests to the API

Comment: @guest  ah! I did not know that. clean solution! upvoted. created a repl to test and it appears to work. https://repl.it/repls/CompassionateDelightfulFunnel

Answer (score 0):

Call `getBaseUrl()` once and save the promise that you get from it. Then in `getFormData()`, call `then` on that saved promise.

```
const getBaseUrl = () => ...

const baseUrlPromise = getBaseUrl()

const getFormData = formId =>
  baseUrlPromise
    .then(...)
```

It's okay to use `.then(...)` multiple times on one promise to make multiple promises that depend on it.

If there's nothing else using `cachedBaseUrl`, you can remove it, because the resolved value will be saved as part of `baseUrlPromise` after it's resolved.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does cache the URL. The problem is that if you were to call this in a loop, numerous `getBaseUrls()` would get queued up before one completes. The cache is set after the first one resolves, but all the other pending promises will still also resolve anyway, spamming the same endpoint. This is the problem the asker is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Klaycon: Already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586153/wait-for-1-promise-before-all-other-promises/59586202?noredirect=1#comment105338829_59586153).

Comment: clairification: earlier comments were deleted. don't call the code snippet in this answer in a loop. it's module top-level code. it's fine to call `getFormData` repeatedly.